# Convert all pixels of a given color to transparent in iMagick (PHP) syntax?

Tags: php, transparency, imagick

I want to convert a given color to transparency with **iMagick**.  I have found one way to do this, but it behaves like a paint bucket rather than examining the entire image.

For the following example, I'm using this:

```
$transparentColor = new ImagickPixel('transparent');  
$image->floodFillPaintImage($transparentColor, 20000, "#0009c5", 0, 0, false, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
```

[This is the input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de8Yf.png)
[This is the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANek9.png)
The result I'd like to see is all the blue areas turned to transparency.  Unfortunately, it seems that "fill" is the key point in this function and hence stops when confronted with non-"target" colors.

Does anyone know how to accomplish turning all the blue areas to transparent using **iMagick** (*not command line **imageMagick***)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Imagick. Changing a color to be transparent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297967/imagick-changing-a-color-to-be-transparent)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$image->transparentPaintImage($targetColor, $alphaLevel, $fuzz, false);
```

If the transparent areas are "messy", it may help to despeckle:

```
$image->despeckleimage();
```

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.transparentpaintimage.php

Comment: That seems to have worked!  The only exception was that this method doesn't seem to accept ImagicPixel('transparent').  
So it finally worked with:

`$image->transparentPaintImage($targetColor, 0.0, $fuzz, false);`

Thanks so much for your help!  Truly appreciated!

Comment: Oh, you are right. Re-reading the doc, the 2nd parameter is the alpha level (0.0 to 1.0). Thanks for the correction - I've edited my answer.